# Add and Remove a Class through a list of Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a list of buttons.

I need to add a clickEvent to each of them, when clicked it needs to check if there's another button with the class(btnActive), remove it and add the class to the clicked button.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < btnAll.length; i++) {
      if (i.classList.contains('btnActive')) {
        i.classList.remove('btnActive');
      }
    }
    el.classList.add('btnActive');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">

  <div class="btn">
    <span class="btnActive">
          0
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
         1
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
          2
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
          3
        </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have that little JS block and I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: btnAll is never defined.

Comment: Sorry I just edited to be more clear. Thanks Markus

Comment: Still not defined. See my answer.

Comment: @MatMol Please don't fix your question's code after you have posted it. People's answers will no longer make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the other answers have covered why your code doesn't work, here's an example where you attach *one* event listener to the container and catch events that bubble up from the other elements (see: [event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)). It makes for more practical code.

```js
// Get the container and the buttons
const container = document.querySelector('.btnContainer');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

// Add a click listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const { target } = e;

  // If a button has been clicked
  if (target.classList.contains('btn')) {

    // Clear any active buttons 
    buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('btnActive'));

    // Make the clicked button active
    target.classList.add('btnActive');
  }
}
```

```css
.btnActive {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">
  <button class="btn btnActive">0</button>
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `.btnActive` class work on the same div that `.btn` is on. Then just loop through the `btnAll` els to remove the class before adding it to the clicked element:

```js
let btnAll = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(function(el1) {
  el1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    btnAll.forEach(function(el2) {
      el2.classList.remove('btnActive');
    });
    el1.classList.add('btnActive');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn.btnActive {
  background: orangered;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">
  <div class="btn">0</div>
  <div class="btn">1</div>
  <div class="btn">2</div>
  <div class="btn">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues:

- You reference `btnAll.length` in your `for` loop but `btnAll` is not defined. You need to define it and assign to it the buttons array.
- You're not actually manipulating an HTML button in your `if` statement. Instead you're attempting to use the `i`(index) which is a number. To reference the actual HTML button you need to do `btnAll[i]`.

That being said, your actual problem is probably not reading the errors that are thrown in your console.

```js
const btnAll = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

btnAll.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < btnAll.length; i++){
            const btn = btnAll[i]

            if(btn.classList.contains('btnActive')){
              btn.classList.remove('btnActive');
            }
        }

        el.classList.add('btnActive');
    });
});
```

```css
.btnActive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">

  <div class="btn">
    <span class="btnActive">
      0
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
     1
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
      2
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
      3
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contained numerous syntax errors:

1. btnAll was not defined.
2. You were attempting to access the dom elements directly through `i`. Use `btnAll[i]` instead.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

var btnAll = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < btnAll.length; i++) {
      if (btnAll[i].classList.contains('btnActive')) {
        btnAll[i].classList.remove('btnActive');
      }
    }
    el.classList.add('btnActive');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn.btnActive
{
  font-weight:900;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">

  <div class="btn">
    <span class="btnActive">
          0
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
         1
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
          2
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span>
          3
        </span>

  </div>
</div>
```